# How to save a file upload to MongoDb in a form along with other data using formidable?

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to save `form data` to `MongoDb`, which also includes an `image file upload`. I use Jquery `form serialize` to send this data to the `server`. The rest of the data gets saved to the database, but not the image. I guess it needs some special treatment. How can I do that? NOTE: I want to be able to send it along with all form data

This is my html part:

```
<!-- SIGNUP for USERS and ADMIN -->
    <div id="pageSignup" class="page popup">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h3>SIGNUP</h3>
            <form class="form" id="frmSignup">
                <input type="text" id="txtEmailorPhoneNumber" name="txtEmailorPhoneNumber" placeholder="Mobile number or Email" required>
                <input type="text" name="txtName" placeholder="Name" required>
                <input type="text" name="txtLastName" placeholder="Lastname" required>
                <input type="password" name="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
                <div class="lblFileUpload">
                    <p>Select your picture:</p>
                    <input type="file" name="fileUserImage" required>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btnShowPage btnForm" id="btnSignupForm">Signup</button>
                <div class="lblFormExtention">
                    <p class="pyesAccount">Already have an account?</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btnShowPage" id="btnLogin" data-showThisPage="pageLogin">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <h3 class="lblErrorMessage" id="lblSignupErrorMessage"></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the jquery serialize part:

```
$('#btnSignupForm').click(function () {
        console.log('btn signup user clicked')
        var oForm = $("#frmSignup").serialize()
        console.log("oForm", oForm)
        var sUrl = 'save-user/'
        console.log("sUrl ", sUrl);
        $.post(sUrl, oForm, function (uData) {
            console.log('SUCCESS')
        })
    })
```

This is my server.js:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var formidable = require('express-formidable');
app.use(formidable());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var fs = require('fs')
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient
global.db = null
var sDatabasePath = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/webshop'
global.mongoId = require('mongodb').ObjectID

/**************************************************/

var user = require(__dirname + '/user.js')

/**************************************************/

app.get('/shopaholic', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(__dirname + '/shopaholic.html') })

mongo.connect(sDatabasePath, (err, db) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR 003 -> Cannot connect to the database')
        return false
    }
    global.db = db
    console.log('OK 002 -> Connected to the database')
    return true
})

/**************************************************/

app.post('/save-user', (req, res) => {
    //var sName = req.fields.userName 
    //console.log("sName ", sName) 
    user.saveUser(req.fields, (err, jResult) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(jResult)
            res.send('ERROR')
            return
        }
        console.log(jResult)
        res.send('OK')
        return
    })
})

/**************************************************/

app.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR 001 -> Cannot listen to port 3000')
        return false
    }
    console.log('OK 000 -> Server listening to port 3000')
})
```

And finally my user.js:

```
var user = {}

/**************************************************/

user.saveUser = (jUserData, fcallback) => {
    var jUser = { "userName": jUserData.txtEmailorPhoneNumber, "firstName": jUserData.txtName, "lastName": jUserData.txtLastName, "password": jUserData.txtPassword, "image": jUserData.fileUserImage }
    global.db.collection('users').insertOne(jUser, (err, jResult) => {
        if (err) {
            var jError = { "status": "error", "message": "ERROR -> user.js -> 001" }
            console.log(jError)
            return fcallback(true, jError)

        }
        var jOk = { "status": "ok", "message": "user.js -> saved -> 000" }
        console.log(jOk)
        return fcallback(false, jOk)
    })
}


/**************************************************/

module.exports = user
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use **multer** module for handling your file uploads and only save **image's path/url** in your mongodb database and let me know if you face any issues with this approach. I will be happy to help.

Comment: isn´t this possible with just formidable?

Comment: It will be but I have personally never worked with it (express-formidable).

Comment: as you can see I am already using it, and it does saves the rest of the data to Mongodb, but not the img upload.  This is what I get in the database:      `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0d92f3b8011348aa8dae2e"),
    "userName" : "a@a.dk",
    "firstName" : "A",
    "lastName" : "A",
    "password" : "1",
    "image" : null
}`

Comment: In your code you are only reading req.fields which is for non-file fields thus
you need to read req.files for files. I hope this is the issue.

Comment: it doesn´t work. I think that actually I can´t just directly send the file to mongoDb, first I need to save the file upload in a folder in my file system and then save that to the db. That´s how I see at many tutorials, but I am also not sure.

Comment: This approach is correct but as a good practice only save image path in database because in future you will be uploading images to different servers (e.g. AWS s3)  in this situation we only save image paths in mongo and images are stored on those servers.

Comment: I decided to use multer instead. You can help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472253/how-to-save-file-upload-path-to-mongodb-using-multer